# WCF service call

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service which takes computer ID,IDs on a network as input parameter and saves the computer stats for past 12 hours[like how much time the computer was locked, active, idle etc..] in the database.

Also I have a website from where I can set the scheduling for few computers at some time t for stats[ for past 12 hours as mentioned above]. This scheduling information[computer is and time] will be saved to database.

**Now the issue is how to use the WCF service to make sure it runs on that particular scheduling time and also how to show the computer stats on the website when the WCF has been called and stats have been generated.**  If I use a window service to call WCF service how will I ensure that it runs on that scheduled time, also how to inform the website that the stats have generated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Set up a Schedule Task that will make call to WCF Service Method you want to run using something like [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

I believe the website needs refreshing so it can pick the data after the WCF Method gets executed so you can again use cUrl to make a web page call